# vim slows down for autocompop for yaml files

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vim-plugin, python-mode, jedi-vim

This is my [vimrc](https://github.com/arunraman/MyVim/blob/master/.vimrc). The vim is really slow in navigation for yaml files. I disabled the L9 and autocompop plugin and its faster now. Is there way to have have the plugin and still have a better navigation. Also I have both pythonmode and jedi-vim for autocompletion. Is it a good practice doing this way ? Is there any alternatives to it.

I was looking into youcompleteme instead of autocomplpop. Would switching to that will help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jedi-vim and python-mode are known for sometimes causing issues (The jedi-vim docs warn about it).

Youcompleteme is an async solution to autocompletion in VIM and therefore definitely faster than autocomplpop (which uses the synchronous omnicomplfunc solutions like `jedi-vim` and `python-mode`.

If it's too slow: I would ditch the autocompletion part of `python-mode`, because it uses rope, which is slower than Jedi. jedi-vim and youcompleteme both use Jedi, but youcompleteme is async and therefore faster.